# Gradle Sync Failed: ‘gradle-wrapper.properties’ not found

Tags: macos, gradle, intellij-idea, build, build.gradle

I am having a problem with Gradle and IntelliJ. I am trying to create a new project with a Gradle build but the Gradle sync fails every time I do so. I have the most recent version of Gradle installed (6.8.3) and am using macOS Big Sur. When I view the Gradle settings for the project, I see the message ‘Gradle-wrapper.properties’ not found. I have no idea what is happening and could really use some help.  I have tried everything from re-installing Gradle and IntelliJ and manually setting the path for the 'Use Gradle From' field in IntelliJ.

[Sync Failed Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GnL2.png)

[Gradle Settings in IntelliJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFFVL.png)

Comment: When creating a new Gradle project IDE first generates the Gradle wrapper and wrapper properties. For this it uses the Gradle task, which it looks like fails for you. What IDE version do you use? Please share the idea.log file (Help | Show Log in ... action) somewhere after reproducing the error.

Comment: @Andrey I realized I never followed up on this.  It turned out my anti-virus software was blocking Gradle from downloading dependencies.